# trouble with auto-height and using CSS to build dynamic forms

Tags: html, css

I am working on a css & div based form and so far it looks good.  However, I am having trouble getting the label side of the form to expand with the content.

The right side expands fine, but I also need the left side to expand with it so it looks good. In the jsFiddle below, you can see that the label 'Genre' does not match up height-wise with the area on the right.

Here is a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MSPAn/6/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="titleArea">
        <label for="name" class="label">Name</label>
        <div class="input">
            <input id="name" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="metaDataArea">
        <label for="genre" class="label">Genre</label>
        <div class="input">
            <select id="genre">
                <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                <option value="nonfiction">Non-fiction</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mediaType">Hardback
            <input type="checkbox" name="mediaType">Paperback
            <input type="checkbox" name="mediaType">eBook
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent {
    width: 550px;
    border: 1px dotted #777;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.label {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    float: left;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: left;
}

.input {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    float: left;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 70%;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Expand with the content? Which content? the label value? Expand how? vertically? horizontally?

Comment: The label side(left side) is not expanding with the right side(form control side)

Comment: I mean vertically...the height.

Comment: When I change "Genre" to "Genre something something" is expands vertically, no problem.

Comment: I am trying to get the 2 sides to have a matching height.  So if one expands, the other expands as well.  I was hoping there was a way to do this with only CSS.  - thanks

Comment: What is "the area on the right"?  Are you expecting it to line up with both the dropdown and the checkboxes?

Comment: my form has a left side, the labels, and a right side, the form controls.  Sometimes in my form, the right side can get rather long, and I'd like the label side to expand with the right side. I was hoping there was a way I could build this such that CSS would take care of the heights. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued to work on this and found a solution.  I created a container div for each form group, and set that to display: table-row.  And then on the form label and form control, I set display: table-cell.  This allows the form to act like a table, but still use modern CSS and div structures.

So it would look like this:

```
<div id="titleArea" style="display: table-row;">
<label for="name" class="label" style="display: table-cell;">Name</label>
<div class="input" style="display: table-cell;">
    <input id="name" type="text" />
</div>
```